# Change default hyper v machine creation settings

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, defaults

I need to constantly create machines in hyper-v, but i am wasting to much time configuring settings like network adapters to with they connect, assigned CPU cores and ram in every single machine that I create.

There is a way that, after running the wizard of the virtual machine creation, the machines are created with more ram or more cores assigned or any settings that I want?

Comment: I can thing of two ways to do this: 1. Use SCVMM to create templates from which to create your virtual machines. 2. Use Powershell to create your virtual machines configured exactly as you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I would use PowerShell, cerate a script that identifies the network configuration that you need and use the script over and over again.

http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/general-virtualization-articles/configuring-virtual-machines-using-powershell.html

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Automate-Virtual-Machine-6c17929c

Comment: While scripting makes sense when many VMs are being created.   Changing the defaults would be preferred for the periodic VM creation.